# Razor MVC 5 ASP.NET form editing with missing Controllers & Models folders on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, octopus-deploy

Hope you guys can give me a clue.

I recently got onto this web developer role and the former person left the company long ago. I'm completely a newbie on MVC or .net development. My knowledge area would be: html, css, java, jsp, php and etc.
There is a web form I need to redesign and I have watched video on Lynda.com:

- Running with ASP.NET
- ASP.NET MVC 5 Essential Training
- c#

Long story short, the production development environment is set as:

1. use Visual Studio 2013 to develop, then check in and build.
2. logon to Octopus Deploy to deploy to Production or Staging

[image]
**dev-portal**(on the left) is the live production source code available on the VS 2013 on the local machine, this is set up by a genius guy I couldn't reach; **4.2.11_9**(on the right) is the staging site I set up on the RD testing server.

I know I need to edit controller and model and view pages to modify the page, however the folders that on the server (we host these pages on our own server) is missing quite a bit. I have no idea where are those folder are hidding.

And also text strings are stored in Resources\Resources.resx

Can anyone give me a clue? This is far more complex for me to figure out, comparing to the video scenario demo on the Lynda.com example.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: *I have no idea where are those folder are hiding* You cannot find `controller` and `model` folder on production server, and your class library converted into DLL, You can find only view page. There is **published code** on production server.

Comment: *I need to edit controller and model* you should have `Source code`

Comment: @Div I have partial source code on the staging site that I set up, but I need to edit those string in the resources.resx !!There is no resources.resx on the staging server.

Comment: @Div Thanks, I need to find the file on the server as I am not going to develop on the VS and then deploy through Octopus Deploy, I tried to set it up that way and it didn't work. I want to modify the code on the server itself.

Comment: Seems not related to TFS in your question, why you add tfs tag?

Comment: hmm, I don't really understand how TFS was set up OR work. The whole system is on TFS. So anything wrong happened, I was told we can roll back through TFS. I will remove the tfs tag if you guys think that's not related. I was just trying to give as much information as I can. @Patrick-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit the code using Visual Studio and test on your local machine.
2. Check your code into TFS. Confirm that a server build has occurred or schedule a new build.
3. Log into Octopus Deploy and confirm a new `release` was recently created.
4. Deploy your release to staging. Confirm the changes. Then deploy to Prod.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Kye I probably need to figure out how to deploy to the staging site I configured..error message show **Could not find certificate under Cert:\LocalMachine with thumbprint 
16a55e04cf0baed19a2c29e20c213473a7314be8.**

Comment: Log onto the machine, open IIS and check if a certificate exists with that thumbprint.

Comment: thanks @Kye, it's working perfectly now. I copied the certification from the production server to the staging server. And I now knows that I need a new **nupkg** file should be created on the Octopus Server once a successful build completed. Octopus Deploy will copy this package over to the destinated server depending on whether I choose to deploy it to the production server or staging server.